# Significant digits in Measure Tool

Tags: measurement

I would like to set the number of significant digits given by the Measure tool.

While measuring I obtain values with 5 significant digits (as seen in the image).

[image]

Could you please tell me how to set Blender to round the number to only 2 significant digits?

I would like to get for this case something like 3.05 mm, instead of 3.05158 mm ...

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

go to view -> measureit tools -> precision

[image]

[image]

UPDATE: Measure

[image]

Move one end with cursor, then hold CTRL and let go on one edge of default cube. Same to other end.

Result:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this is an excelent walkaround if you are working in Edit mode, using the Measurelt Tool Add-on.

Comment: However, do know how to do it in the Object Mode, using the standard Measure Tool (second icon from the bottom in the the left tool bar)? Thanks a lot.

Comment: first - this tool also show measurements in object mode. "Your tool" cannot do this (AFAIK), but does it automatically, if the value e.g. is 2m it shows 2m. Just get the end of your newly created measurement, hold CTRL and draw it to one edge of the default cube. Do the same to the other end -> voila -> 2m

Comment: i updated my answer

Comment: Perfect. Thanks a lot!

Comment: you are welcome. would be nice if you would tap on the checkmark left to my answer ;) -> this means: this solution is ok for you